# How to reorder sections of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop

[This question from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502243/how-to-reorder-section-in-uitableview-by-dragging-similar-to-row) wasn't answered, and it is one of the very few mentions of this problem on the Internet.

The problem: I want to re-order the sections of a UITableView in the same way I can do with the rows (i.e., by dragging).

The way I see this working like is: you turn on editing on the table, re-order indicators appear. When you start dragging a section header (or a cell acting as a fake section header, which is sub-optimal [1]), all the regular cells "disappear", so you can only move sections around (and it is easier if you have more than a handful of sections).

[LPRTableView](https://github.com/nicolasgomollon/LPRTableView) appears to address the problem, but it is quite tricky to set up correctly when re-ordering sections. I tried for a full day with not very much success. Plus, [1].

A not-so-great-but-acceptable solution is to have buttons like ⬆️⬇️ in the headers (proper headers can be used here) but it is a little awkward.

Another not-so-great-but-acceptable solution is to have an extra step (like, a button) that brings up a new UITableView showing only the sections as cells, and allow re-ordering there. Works fine, but creates more issues than it solves [2].

I can't see anything in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) by way of, for example, a hook called when re-ordering starts/ends. Or rather, there is the [ending](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614867-tableview) bit but I can't see the beginning one.

Suggestions?

---

[1] This allows rows to be placed before the section header, in principle, and you have to manually catch that, with a bad-looking visual effect.

[2] Where would I even place such a control, especially if I have a crowded UI already, or I want to keep my UI minimal?

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564810/how-to-let-the-user-reorder-sections-in-a-uitableview

Comment: I saw that but it won't allow me to move cells from one section to another.

Comment: Have you 

tried func moveSection(_ section: Int, toSection newSection: Int)
?

Comment: Yes, but there is no way of dragging and dropping the sections. If I had up and dow buttons, that function is what I'd use *after* the fact.

Comment: There is no 'built in' standard method to do this provided by the UITableView control so you need to hand craft one yourself.  Looking at the link provided by @AhmadF you could try doing something with tap gestures or possibly pan gestures to start and control the moving of the sections.

Comment: Do you need to support both reordering cells and sections, or is it sections-only? If it's the latter, I think the approach you marked as [2] is pretty nice -- when the "edit" button is tapped, just change the tableview's data source to a simpler model with a single section, where the sections of the original table are represented as cells; this way you can use the built-in ordering features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go the way to collapse all sections and display only the sectionHeaders as UITableViewCells. Then i would rearrange them with the default drag and drop behaviour. When finished, then load the old uncollapsed info back into the table view cell.

Then you don't have to think about animations and stick to the "iOS Guidelines".

Comment: I'm considering doing that, but the question remains as to how I trigger that functionality. It has to be easy to discover (i.e., no long tap on header or other obscure gestures) and it has to not clutter the UI (rules out a button somewhere).

Comment: Maybe have disclosure indicator, but one which is pointing up in the section header? Or just an edit bar button item would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of fake section you can tap and drag that section view. There two steps for that:

1. First make delegate to recognise which section of uitableview is
   under you tap(i hope you can do this, i'm not going into the
   details).
2. Than drop it to some section which have to be replace. So for
   replacing there are also two ideas in my mind.

   First playing the views
   hierarchy whats on top what is under it, than by help of tagging or
   something else get the section under you replacing fake section.

   Second could be the find the visible cell than calculate by the
   screen position what could be the section here.

When you can achieve this, you have have both sections, you can replace both in the data source and than load the data again.

Comment: This is what LPRTableView does. I tried that, but it's quite tricky to set-up with sections (see it mentioned in my OP).

Comment: Don't use LPRTableView you can do it yourself its not that tricky i think . If you're not that good with the tableview than it could be a problem. Let me see LPRTableView if I find something than i will back to you.