# How to reorder section in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, reorderlist

I want to reorder section and row. So by default, native section reordering is not possible. So I implemented the section as a row. And reorder section and row. But the problem is when I reorder the section then it takes a row. It will crash the application.

Can you please help me?

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). Table view: <UITableView: 0x7f874f026000; frame = (0 59; 393 759); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000023bde60>; backgroundColor = <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x60000388b640; name = tableBackgroundColor>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002df4c60>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {393, 206.66667175292969}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <ReorderTableView.ViewController: 0x7f874c709840>>

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
    
    var arrSection = [Section]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       
        tblView.isEditing = true
        tblView.dataSource = self
        tblView.delegate = self
        // register tableviewcell
        tblView.register(UINib(nibName:"SectionTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SectionTableViewCell")
        setupView()
    }
    
    func setupView(){
        let obj = Group(groupName: "Group1")
        let sec = Section(sectionName: "Section1", group: [obj])
        let sec1 = Section(sectionName: "Section2", group: [obj])
        arrSection.append(sec)
        arrSection.append(sec1)
        tblView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arrSection.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if arrSection[section].group?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
            let temp = arrSection[section].group?.count ?? 0
            return temp + 1
        }
        else{
            return 1
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let obj = arrSection[indexPath.section]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SectionTableViewCell") as! SectionTableViewCell
            cell.lblTitle.text = obj.sectionName
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let obj = arrSection[indexPath.section].group?[indexPath.row - 1]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SectionTableViewCell") as! SectionTableViewCell
            cell.lblTitle.text = obj?.groupName ?? ""
            return cell
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }else{
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        tblView.beginUpdates()
        let movingItem = self.arrSection[sourceIndexPath.section]
        self.arrSection.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.section)
        self.arrSection.insert(movingItem, at: destinationIndexPath.section)
        tblView.moveSection(sourceIndexPath.section, toSection: destinationIndexPath.section)
        tblView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772457/swift-reorder-uitableview-cells, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521589/swift-reorder-table-rows-programmatically, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607403/reordering-sections-in-uitableview, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392766/how-to-reorder-sections-of-a-uitableview

Comment: The error message is essentially saying that there was only one cell in your first section before the reorder, but two cells after.  At a glance, that seems weird, as you immediately add two sections, both with exactly one cell (group), and it should "correctly" return 1+1=2 in numberOfRows due to your temp "sectionHeader=cell"-logic. From what I can see, the tableView should always assume there's two rows in each section, so I'm not sure why it believes it was one cell at any point unless your if-check in numberOfRows fails. Try debugging, or at least print out statements so you see.

Comment: @Sti can you please tell me i want delete row and that row convert to section.i already done code but problem is code is working in iphone but when i run in mac catalytic that time app crash.

Comment: @Jones What do you mean? Your words make no sense. This post was about rearranging cells, not about deleting rows, "row convert to section", or "catalytic" crashes?

Comment: @Sti please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75092807/attempt-to-perform-a-delete-and-a-move-from-the-same-index-path-how-to-delete-s