# attempt to perform a delete and a move from the same index path in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mac-catalyst

In my application there is some functionality.i want to create logic like Row move to section.means movable row is removed to section and that movable row is conver to section.so first i will try to delete that row in section than after create new section..than app crash in mac-catalyst

> 2023-01-12 12:41:43.227580+0530 ReorderTableView[4186:142282]
> [General] attempt to perform a delete and a move from the same index
> path (<NSIndexPath: 0xd380cd7e557f0a2f> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1})

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        // tblView.beginUpdates()
        print("Source" , sourceIndexPath)
        print("Destination",destinationIndexPath)
        arrSection[sourceIndexPath.section].group?.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row - 1)
        self.tblView.beginUpdates()
        self.tblView.deleteRows(at: [sourceIndexPath], with: .fade)
        self.tblView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Comment: Your question and requirements are very unclear. The error is obvious. You are trying to delete the same row that is being moved inside the `moveRowAt` method. Why would you try to delete the row currently being moved? Please update your question with a much better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @HangarRash In my application there is some functionality.i want to create logic like Row move to section.means movable row is removed to section and that movable row is conver to section.so first i will try to delete that row in section than after create new section.

Comment: Unrelated but `beginUpdates/endUpdates` is useless for a single delete operation..